# Google Cloud Storage - Insufficient Permissions

Tags: php, api, cloud, storage, credentials

I am getting an Error 403: InsufficientPermissions error with Google Cloud Storage when trying to upload a file to a bucket in PHP. This just started happening out of the blue, after being able to do it successfully for months. I have enabled the service account access to **literally everything** in IAM and in the Bucket permissions. I have created a new account and added new permissions. Was there a change to how we must authenticate GCS in 2017?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your **service account** to be able to insert a new object into a bucket, you need to make sure that the service account email has at least **Editor** access on the Bucket ACLs or the **Storage Object Creator** (roles/storage.objectCreator) role in the Project IAM Policy.

Based on the date of your post, it's possible you were affected by a GCS outage that occurred on July 6th between 2:34pm and 4pm (eastern).

https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/storage/17002

> July 6, 2017 2:50pm:
>
> We are experiencing an intermittent issue with Google Cloud Storage -
>   JSON API requests are failing with 5XX errors (XML API is unaffected)
>   beginning at Thursday, 2017-07-06 16:50:40 US/Pacific. Current data
>   indicates that approximately 70% of requests globally are affected by
>   this issue. For everyone who is affected, we apologize for any
>   inconvenience you may be experiencing. We will provide an update by
>   18:30 US/Pacific with current details.

Comment: Thank you sir! It appears I was one of the effected!